# postfix in a jail how to notify blacklistd running in main host

Tags: postfix, freebsd

I have [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) compiled with [blacklistd](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/firewalls-blacklistd.html) support running in a [jail](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/jails.html).

On the main host (FreeBSD 12.1) `blascklistd` is running with this config:

```
# Blacklist rule
# adr/mask:port type    proto   owner           name    nfail   disable
[local]
submission      stream  *       *               *       2       24h
```

How to configure `postfix` to notify `blacklistd` running on the main host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another socket to blacklistd in base

vim /etc/rc.conf

```
blacklistd_enable="YES"
blacklistd_flags="-r -s /var/run/blacklistd.sock"
blacklistd_jails="jail1 jail2"
for i in ${blacklistd_jails}
do
        blacklistd_flags="${blacklistd_flags} -s /jail/${i}/var/run/blacklistd.sock"
done
```

The programs in the jails (postfix, sendmail, sshd) just report to the default socket.